# Distinguish between elements and last element of array

Tags: php, html

Im creating tablerows based on the number of the array colours:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM things);
$num = mysql_num_rows($query );
$colours = array ();

if($num)
{
    for ($i = 0; ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)); ++$i)
    {   
        $colours[$i] = $row["colours"];
    }
}


$arrlength = count($colours);
for ($i = 0; ($i < ($arrlength)); ++$i){            
    echo "
         <tr class='border_bottom'><td>".$colours[$i]."</td></tr>
    ";
}
```

So, if colours is, lets say, equal to 8, 8 table rows with the class border_bottom are created.

border_bottom is used by CSS to add a border to the bottom of each tablerow.

What I need is some PHP help: I need code which checks the array colours. The last element of the array has to go with an empty id since I dont want a border-bottom added to that very last tablerow. All other tablerows have to go with the border_bottom class, tho.
I was thinking of starting the code like that:

```
echo"
<tr class='
";
-->PHP code goes here<--
echo"
'>
<td>".$colours[$i]."</td></tr>
```

Comment: You are right, my bad. Any suggestion tho how to fix the problem using class?

Comment: that's invalid html. `id` **MUST** be unique across the entire document.

Comment: It is, its example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM things");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$colours = array();

if($num)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {   
        $colours[] = $row["colours"];
    }
}

$arrlength = count($colours);
for ($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; ++$i){ 
    if($i < $arrlength - 1){
        echo "<tr class='border_bottom'><td>{$colours[$i]}</td></tr>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td>{$someColor}</td></tr>";
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your table row echo

```
echo "<tr"
    .($i < $arrlength - 1 ? " class='border_bottom'" : "")
    .">"
    ."<td>{$colours[$i]}</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this while fetching the rows without needing to count how many there are, by reading ahead one row.

```
$previous_row = mysql_fetch_array();  // fetch the first row (if there is one)
while ($previous_row) {
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array()) {
        // if another row is fetched, then the previous row was NOT the last row
        echo '<tr class="border_bottom"><td>' . $previous_row['colours'] . '</td></tr>';
    } else {
        // otherwise, the previous row WAS the last row, and does not get the class
        echo '<tr><td>' . $previous_row['colours'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $previous_row = $row;  // Set the previous row to the current row
}
```

Comment: interesting way of looking at it